# Clustering analysis of a weighted graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, clustering

My data consists of a large weighted undirected graph of $n$ nodes. I need to group the nodes into $m$ clusters ($m < n$), such that nodes in a cluster are connected with heavy weights. What algorithms are available for this problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339576/delete-minium-weight-edges-to-disconnect-a-set-of-nodes

Answer (score 1):

Some keywords and starting references:

- [Spectral clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering)
- [Community detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure#Algorithms_for_finding_communities)

Answer (score -1):

Walktrap and the Louvain algorithms work very well with weighted undirected graphs.

You may find them in most modern graph libraries.